# Select specific date from datatable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to select and re-assign the datatable after spesific hour. I use below code;

```
dtMasterPivot = dtMasterPivot.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME").Hour >= 4).CopyToDataTable();
```

Like above what i want is only select the data after 04:00. However, it doesn't work. It still brings the before 04:00.

Comment: Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do other statements work in the where?

Comment: @EpicKip yes, it all works.

Comment: @doctorcesar then without any other context I have no clue why it would not work

Comment: @doctorcesar I just tested this and its somewhere else in your code as that line works just fine

Answer (score -1):

This works as advertised:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dT = new DataTable();
        dT.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dT.Columns.Add("Sample_Time", typeof(DateTime));
        dT.Columns.Add("Misc", typeof(string));

        var row = dT.NewRow();
        row[0] = 1;
        row[1] = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3, 15, 15, 0);
        row[2] = "3:15 PM";
        dT.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dT.NewRow();
        row[0] = 2;
        row[1] = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3, 3, 59, 0);
        row[2] = "3:59 AM";
        dT.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dT.NewRow();
        row[0] = 3;
        row[1] = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3, 12, 0, 0);
        row[2] = "Noon";
        dT.Rows.Add(row);

        dT = dT.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Sample_Time").Hour >= 4).CopyToDataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < dT.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((string)dT.Rows[i][2]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Silly question really, but are you sure about your field names? And also whether you are using 12/24 hour clock?